# jQuery Mobile load a specific set of icons for a theme?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to load a specific set of icons for a theme? I tried using `data-theme=c` and that didn't work

Css

```css
[data-theme=c].ui-icon,
[data-theme=c].ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background-image: url(../images/icons-18-black.png) /*{global-icon-set}*/;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius:                 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius:              9px;
    border-radius:                      9px;
}
```

html

```html
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page4" data-transition="slide">
                            Items
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Do you need quotes in `[data-theme="c"]` ?

Comment: @jmort253 adding quotes did not work. hmm

Comment: Make sure you use more specific CSS selectors than what jQuery UI is using. Also, try using a `<style></style>` block to test these in to make sure your selectors are right. Style blocks take higher precedence over external CSS. If that doesn't work, then your CSS rules are broken. If it does work, then you need more specific CSS selectors.

Comment: @jmort253 I have a few other custom data-theme's set for corners and buttons and those work fine. its just not reading the .ui-icon as a custom/specific theme set

Comment: I understand, and that might be because your CSS selectors are not more specific than the CSS selectors in the jQuery UI CSS **for the icons.**. Without more information, all I can do is recommend things for you to try.  If it helps, I've dealt with this problem before, and more specific CSS selectors helped. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a space in between [data-theme=c] and .ui-icon.

```
[data-theme=c] .ui-icon,
[data-theme=c] .ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background-image: url(../images/icons-18-black.png);
}
```

If that doesn't work your path is also wrong try putting full url to test that.

```
background-image: url(http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/images/icons-18-black.png);
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/CDUth/4/

Comment: did not work, there is already a default icon set, and that's be loaded instead. it's not reading the specific one i'm setting for the black icon. only the default while one is shown. Now if I comment out the default .ui-icon and leave [data-theme=c] .ui-icon (as in your example) it works. i'm trying to run two sets at once

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused as to what you want. Could you make a jsfiddle illustrating what your trying to do?